# Nodejs + db-mysql Segmentation Fault

Tags: mysql, node.js

I don't know what causes it, but I have a Node app that keeps crashing. The console says Segmentation Fault, and it looks like it happens when two Mysql objects are instantiated (using db-mysql module), which becomes very common when 10+ users are using my site (I don't post the link to the app because I'm afraid the load would crash it ;) if it can be useful I'll post it).

Do you guys have any clue? My packages are up to date. Do you have a better package to use with Mysql (assuming it's where the problem lies)? Do you also encounter Segfault issues using Nodejs (I guess not, bcs stability is one of the main advantges of Node)?

Comment: are you getting a stack dump when the segfault occurs? That might be helpful...

Comment: sometimes I do, sometimes just "Segmentation fault". How can I retrieve the dump?

Comment: It would generally just come up in the console... I'm not sure how to get at it otherwise unless you catch exceptions and output it to the console from your code.

Comment: I can see it in the console, but then it seems like it's lost forever... I'm gonna look into the documentation, there must be a way to retrieve logs.

Answer (score 0):

I [think] I was definitely doing something wrong: cerating a new MySQL object and connecting to the DB every time I had a reaquest. Instead, I stored the MySQL object and run a single query for each... query. Working fine so far.